# Problem with getSelectedRow and removeRow not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am writing a program in which there is a JTable that I need to remove some selected rows from. Here is the method that removes a selected row (or shows a pop-up saying that the a row wasn't selected if it was not) and displays the modified JTable in the viewPort:

```
public static void removeRow(JTable table, MainWindow frm){
        if(table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
            table = new JTable(model);
            table.clearSelection();
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "No row selected. Try again!",
                    "Selection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frm.mainScrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
```

The method works the first time a row is selected, however, when doing the same thing again the pop-up appears (though a selection was made). The third time the code works as was intended. So, every odd attempt the code works, and every even attempt it does not.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: *table = new JTable(model);* Why? And anyway that's not going to work as Java is pass-by-value. The incoming parameter will therefore by unaltered

Comment: @g00se , thought that I had to change the viewport each time I made a change to the table in MainWindow. Removing this line and the setViewportView() worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: so you delete the first line (x), it works, then try the new first line (y), it fails, then again the same first line (y), it works etc?